# Scifi movie where two factions fight in space. On the planet below, a similar struggle is going on with cavemen protagonists

Tags: story-identification

I saw this live-action movie more than 30 years ago (1985 or before)

There were 2 factions fighting in space, they wore similar outfits, one white with a brown pattern (possibly a circle?) on the chest, and the other brown with a white pattern. I think it was white and brown, it may have been white and something else.

Down on the planet below, there were primitive people divided into the same factions, wearing sort of caveman versions of the same outfits.

I don't really remember the relationship between the advanced and the primitive, but they did come face to face toward the end.. pretty sure they spoke to each other.

Toward the end someone got crushed by falling rocks.

Comment: Can you recall anything else? This may not be enough to identify the movie (particularly if you have the colors wrong).

Comment: I'm trying to remember! lol. I'm fairly sure it was white and brown!

Comment: What were the patterns? Why were the primitives wearing the same clothes? Do you remember anything about the space people (who they were, what they were called) How were they fighting in space (ship to ship, hand to hand?)

Comment: Was it a live action movie or animation?

Comment: Live action, and patterns were simple, i think it might have been like a circle. I don't really remember the relationship between the advanced and the primitive, but they did come face to face toward the end..

Comment: Sounds like a proxy war between super powers.

Answer (score 3):

**[Yor: Hunter From the Future](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084935/)?**

It has the cavemen, the collapse, the advanced and primitive races in the colours you mention. They meet before the end of the film. Though it has [nuclear war survivors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yor,_the_Hunter_from_the_Future) with aircraft (saucers, jets) rather than spaceships as the advanced race.

Comment: This is definitely along a similar theme, but it's not the one unfortunately! Looks cheesy enough for a watch though! thanks!